# Dudas sobre Error en javaScript,

Tags: javascript, html, c#, ajax, .net

Actualmente estoy trabajando con entity framework y ajax, tengo un metodo en ajax que me regresa una lista que puedo cargar en una tabla y cuando quiero escoger alguno item en especial doy click a la fila y estos datos los carga en formulario, generalmento los cargo en TextBoxFor:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.SubjectId, new { @class = "form-control", @required = "Required", @id = "SubjectTxt", @style = "visibility:hidden" })
```

el problema esta en que la funcion que tengo en javascript para que cargue esta funcion lo hace perfectamente para numeros pero cuando los datos son caracteres o tipo string me aparece este error, en este caso Lectoescritura es el contenido de la variable que quiero pasar:

```
Create:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: Lectoescritura is not defined
at HTMLInputElement.onclick
```

El metodo onclick que va a la funcion es:

```
"<input type='button' onclick='PasarMateria(" + value.SubjectId + "," + value.NameSubject + " )' class='btn btn-warning' value='Seleccionar' data-dismiss='modal'>"
```

y la funcion en javascript:

```
function PasarMateria(SubjectId, NameSubject) {

        $("#SubjectTxt").val(SubjectId);
        $("#SubjectLbn").val(NameSubject);           

        console.log(SubjectId);

    }
```

el metodo ajax completo

```
@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {



            $("#SearchSubjectBtn").click(function () {
                alert("se dio click en el boton");
                var SearchBySubject = $("#SearchBySubject").val();
                var SearchSubject = $("#SearchSubject").val();
                var SetDataSubject = $("#DataSearchingSubject");

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/Generic/GetSubject?SearchBy=" + SearchBySubject + "&SearchValue=" + SearchSubject,
                    contentType: "html",
                    success: function (result) {
                        console.log(result);

                        if (result.length == 0) {
                            window.alert("no se encontro la materia");
                            SetDataSubject.append('<tr style="color:red"><td colspan="3">No se encontro la materia</td></tr>')
                        }

                        else {

                            $.each(result, function (i, value) {
                                var Data = "<tr>" +                                    
                                    "<td>" + value.NameSubject + "</td>" +                                   
                                    "<td>" + value.NameLevel + "</td>" +                                  
                                    "<td>" +
                                    "<input type='button' onclick='PasarMateria(" + value.SubjectId + ",'" + value.NameSubject + "' )' class='btn btn-warning' value='Seleccionar' data-dismiss='modal'>" +
                                    "</td>" +
                                    "</tr>";

                                SetDataSubject.append(Data);
                            });
                        }

                    }
                });

            });


        });




        function PasarUsuario(UserId, nombre) {

            $("#txtUsuario").val(UserId);
            $("#borrartxt").val(nombre);
            document.getElementById('borrartxt').innerHTML = nombre;

            console.log(UserId);

        }

        function PasarMateria(SubjectId, NameSubject) {

            console.log('SubjectId', typeof SubjectId);
            console.log('NameSubject', typeof NameSubject);

            $("#SubjectTxt").val(SubjectId);
            $("#SubjectLbn").val(NameSubject);


            console.log(SubjectId);

        }
    </script>
}

    @section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {




            $("#SearchSubjectBtn").click(function () {
                alert("se dio click en el boton");
                var SearchBySubject = $("#SearchBySubject").val();
                var SearchSubject = $("#SearchSubject").val();
                var SetDataSubject = $("#DataSearchingSubject");

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/Generic/GetSubject?SearchBy=" + SearchBySubject + "&SearchValue=" + SearchSubject,
                    contentType: "html",
                    success: function (result) {
                        console.log(result);

                        if (result.length == 0) {
                            window.alert("no se encontro la materia");
                            SetDataSubject.append('<tr style="color:red"><td colspan="3">No se encontro la materia</td></tr>')
                        }

                        else {

                            $.each(result, function (i, value) {
                                var Data = "<tr>" +                                    
                                    "<td>" + value.NameSubject + "</td>" +                                   
                                    "<td>" + value.NameLevel + "</td>" +                                  
                                    "<td>" +
                                    "<input type='button' onclick='PasarMateria(" + value.SubjectId + ",'" + value.NameSubject + "' )' class='btn btn-warning' value='Seleccionar' data-dismiss='modal'>" +
                                    "</td>" +
                                    "</tr>";

                                SetDataSubject.append(Data);
                            });
                        }

                    }
                });

            });


        });




        function PasarUsuario(UserId, nombre) {

            $("#txtUsuario").val(UserId);
            $("#borrartxt").val(nombre);
            document.getElementById('borrartxt').innerHTML = nombre;

            console.log(UserId);

        }

        function PasarMateria(SubjectId, NameSubject) {



            $("#SubjectTxt").val(SubjectId);
            $("#SubjectLbn").val(NameSubject);


            console.log(SubjectId);

        }
    </script>
}
```

aqui quiero poner lo que encuentre

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h3>Buscar Materia</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="form-inline">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.SubjectId, new { @class = "form-control", @required = "Required", @id = "SubjectTxt", @style = "visibility:hidden" })
                    <label id="SubjectLbn">Materia no relacionada</label>

                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Lo que me tiene confundido es por que me presenta error cuando el resultado que le doy a NameSubject es tipo string y no cuando es entero y si debo declara NameSubject de tipo string como lo hago, tengo entendido que javascript es flexible con el tema de tipo de variable.

Gracias

Comment: No tampoco funciona. de esa manera

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intenta agregandole comilla simple al `value.NameSubject`:

```
"<input type='button' onclick='PasarMateria(" + value.SubjectId + ", '" + value.NameSubject + "' )' class='btn btn-warning' value='Seleccionar' data-dismiss='modal'>"
```

Tambien modifca la funcion `PasarMateria` para que imprimas en consola el tipo de dato que le llega a la funcion:

```
function PasarMateria(SubjectId, NameSubject) {
    console.log('SubjectId', typeof SubjectId);
    console.log('NameSubject', typeof NameSubject);

    $("#SubjectTxt").val(SubjectId);
    $("#SubjectLbn").val(NameSubject);

    //fuerza a convertir a string el NameSubject como forma de prueba.
    //$("#SubjectLbn").val('' + NameSubject);

    console.log(SubjectId);

}
```

Como no especificas donde armas el input, si en un js o del lado del servidor, ni tampoco especificas la estructura de `value` y sus propiedades, no puedo darte mas detalles de como solucionar tu inconveniente.

***Actualizando:***

Lo mas seguro es que en el onClick cuando se pasa una cadena el explorador interpreta mal la doble comilla con la comilla simple.

Intenta mejor pasar todo el objeto `value` a la funcion `PasarMateria`:

Crea el input de esta forma:

```
"<input type='button' onclick='PasarMateria(" + JSON.stringify(value) + " )' class='btn btn-warning' value='Seleccionar' data-dismiss='modal'>"
```

Y actualiza la funcion:

```
function PasarMateria(value) {
    $("#SubjectTxt").val(value.SubjectId);
    $("#SubjectLbn").val(value.NameSubject);
    console.log(value.SubjectId);
}
```

Comment: Buen dia Orlando, la verdad no llega a imprimir en consola por que cuando entra en la funcion PasarMateria me arroja el error: Uncaught ReferenceError: Ingles is not defined at HTMLInputElement.onclick...... ajax lo que me trae es este objeto: 0:
DescriptionSubject: null
NameLevel: "primero"
NameSubject: "Ingles-primero"
SubjectId: 1

Comment: Entonces la creacion del input button esta en el success del ajax y value es el item que recorres para crear la tabla ???

Comment: Cuando utilizo comillas simples me arroja este error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input

Comment: podrias mostrar el html final de la tabla que creaste, para verificar como quedan los valores en el input del onclick='PasarMateria'

Comment: en el value del item

Comment: una vez cargada la pagina revisa la tabla y verifica el atributo onClick

Comment: presiona f12 en el explorador y revisa el html

Comment: voy a editar la pregunta y paso el codigo completo de la pagina donde quiero cargar.

Comment: al final de tu pregunta agrega, Actualizando, y colocas lo nuevo. de esta forma el post se mantiene con lo original y es mas facil de leer para los demas. No cometas el error de borrar todo la pregunta por que los demas comentarios quedarian sin sentido.

Comment: entonces el error aparece cuando le haces click a `#SearchSubjectBtn` o cuando le haces click al input que ya creaste en el ajax. Ademas en el `contentType: "html"` deberias de cambiarlo, ese valor indica que tipo de datos esta enviando al servidor y no creo que sea html

Comment: cuando hago click en el input que creo en ajax

Comment: Este es el json que me llega del ajax, no tengo problema con el SubjectId que es de tipo number :                                                      DescriptionSubject: null
NameLevel: "primero"
NameSubject: "Ingles-primero"  
SubjectId: 1

Comment: revisa la respuesta la e actualizado

Comment: muchas gracias me sirvio pasando el objeto completo a la funcion..